# Linq expression throws an ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, linq

GetSpecialNodes returns null sometimes.  When it does, I get an ArgumentNullException thrown.  Is there an elegant way of handling (a change to the linq expression) this besides calling GetSpecialNodes before running the Linq expression and doing a null check?

```
var nodes = (from HtmlNode node in document.GetSpecialNodes() select node);
```

Comment: Has `document` a value or is it null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be

```
var nodes = (document.GetSpecialNodes() ?? new List<HtmlNode>()).ToList<HtmlNode>()
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are doing more than just selecting the nodes coming from `GetSpecialNodes()`. Thus you probably want to avoid calling `ToList()` on `GetSpecialNodes()` to profit from deferred execution. You can use `Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>()` to create an empty set:

```
var nodes = document.GetSpecialNodes() ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>();
```

I think your code will be more readable when you do this before defining the query:

```
var nodes = document.GetSpecialNodes() ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>();
var result = from HtmlNode node in nodes where /* some predicate */
```

vs.

```
var nodes = (from HtmlNode node in (document.GetSpecialNodes() ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>()) where /* some predicate */)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option, change `GetSpecialNodes()` so it returns `Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>()` instead of `null`. It's always better to return an empty collection instead of null, then you can just check the collection for items using `.Any()` extension method.

Or as Stefan suggested:

```
var nodes = 
  from HtmlNode node in (document.GetSpecialNodes() ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>())
  select node;
```